# Why Mathematica is not computing this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Why is the following integral not computed

```
 Integrate[(Exp[-t] - 1)/
 Sqrt[2 + Exp[-2 t] - Exp[-t] - 
   Exp[t (-(1/2) - I a) - Exp[t (-(1/2) + I a)]]], {t, 0, 1}]?
```

Comment: Rubi cannot do it either. Some integrals are just too hard - some even have [no closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) in elementary functions - and your double exponential under a square root is probably what makes it so difficult. You will need to resort to numerics with `NIntegrate`, but to do that you must give `a` some value - it cannot remain a symbol but you could make a function: `intg[a_?NumericQ]:= NIntegrate[...]`

Comment: Thanks @flinty. Actually I need to plot the result with respect to $a$. Don't know how to proceed...

Comment: From comment of user @flinty, try: `Plot[intg[a] // ReIm // Evaluate, {a, -2, 2}]`

Comment: You also could try using `ParametricNDSolveValue` with `a` as the parameter.  It may be faster than `NIntegrate`, provided `a` is not too large.

Comment: Personal opinion: I think any similar question should be closed unless the asker can convincingly explain why they believe that Mathematica should be able to solve the integral, differential equation, or any other hard problem.

Comment: However, most of these are "XY problems" (@Mike: please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), just like this one. How to solve this symbolically, and how to plot the result as a function of `a` are entirely different problems (with the latter being much simpler).